# How to manipulate a column selected by * in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want a query to return all rows and all columns with one caveat: if, in a given row, colN is null, then instead return the string 'FOO'.

**Why dont I just use `SELECT col1, col2, ..., COALESCE(colN, 'FOO')`?**

I am implementing an abstract interface and thus I am required to use `SELECT` queries which `SELECT *` (because I cannot make assumptions on what columns there are). I can only assume 1 columns exists: colN.

**What would this provide me?**

I need this because this query is used in combination with a UNION and this allows me to keep track of the origin of the data.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is

```
SELECT *, COALESCE(colN, 'FOO') as CoalescedColN
```

if it's possible to adjust the other select(s) in the `UNION` accordingly

Comment: The problem with this is that it adds an extra column. Is there any way to remove colN?

Comment: None that I know of. As far as I know, in SQL you can either use `*` or explicitly specify the selected columns, there's no way to say _"all columns except X"_

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if SQL Lite can use this technique but this is what I would do in most other dbs:

select * from 
(SELECT col1, col2, ..., COALESCE(colN, 'FOO') from table ) a

Comment: this doesnt help because I dont know the names of the columns

Comment: thats not the point: it is an interface. I.e. the names change from one time the function is called to the next.